# get\set cookie using TOR API c#

Tags: torsocks, cookies

I'm trying to get and set cookies using the Tor API.
The problem is that the `SocksPortHandler` doesn't have `CookieContainer` nor `InnerHandler`.

I tried using `Knapcode.SocketToMe.Http.CookieHandler` and set its `InnerHandler` to `SocksPortHandler`, but with no success. here is the code -

```
  using (CookieHandler cookieHandler = new CookieHandler())
            {
                SocksPortHandler socksPortHandler = new SocksPortHandler("127.0.0.1", socksPort: 9050);
                cookieHandler.InnerHandler = socksPortHandler;
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(cookieHandler))
                {
                   .....setting httpClient properties.....
                    HttpResponseMessage message = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result;
                    response = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    cookieHeader = cookieHandler.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(uri);
                }
            }
```

how can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just found the answer https://github.com/nopara73/DotNetTor/issues/18
hope it will help others

Comment: Could you describe with a few more words what helped you? Thanks.